# How to detect click in GridView

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a GridView, and in this Gridview there are several Grids which contain other elements. If I click onto one element of my GridView (one Grid) I want to open details about this element, but Grid and GridView dont seem to support setting a click method. What else can I do to call a method when an element is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

> but Grid and GridView dont seem to support setting a click method

Use `Tapped` event.

Comment: It seems like it works, but only if I press on a visible part of the grid like a textblock, but not on the invisible parts. How can I make it work there too?

Comment: @CodeSharpMarvin Could you share the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

you could add an invisible rectangle or other element to register an OnMouseOver event or click ect.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your `Grid` should subscribe to 3 events and have transparent background:

```
 <Grid Background="Transparent" PointerPressed="Grid_OnPointerPressed" PointerReleased="Grid_OnPointerReleased" PointerExited="Grid_OnPointerExited">
```

in code you may simulate click event like this:

```
    private bool _isPressed;

    private void Grid_OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    private void Grid_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            //your logic on click event
        }

        _isPressed = false;
    }

    private void Grid_OnPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }
```

or the easiest way is to wrap your `Grid` into `Button`